# Sql Error 1064,Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query

```
Select * from `products`
where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR
       `product_company`= 'dunkin donuts')
AND (`flavour`='vanilla')
AND (355 < `price` < 561 ) ;
```

Which fetches me elements greater than some fixed price and less than some fixed price.It also includes other constraints as well.However when i run this sql query it gives me a

> > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Select * from `products` where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR `product' at line 1.

I checked my sql syntax and i don't seem to get the problem.Anyone ,Please?

Comment: `355 < price < 561 `  doesn't jive with some rdbms, not sure about mysql.

Comment: What comes immediately before 'SELECT' in your code.

Comment: I do see that you have an extra " on the last line near the semicolon. Copy and paste error or is it actually in your code? You will want to change the last line to between like Ed's answer after you remove the "

Comment: You aren't trying to perform multiple statements in one call without a delimiter, are you? The `syntax to use near '"Select * from products` suggests something like that, since it points to the character _before_ the `Select`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support that syntax - but it wouldn't error out.

Comment: You have to show us your actual code.

Comment: @Strawberry Got my answer,thanks.FYI,I love strawberry :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
355 < price < 561)
```

to

```
price between 356 and 560
```

to correct the problem (between includes equals so need to shrink the range)

i.e.

```
Select * from `products`
    where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR
           `product_company`= 'dunkin donuts')
    AND (`flavour`='vanilla')
    AND price between 355 and 561
```

Comment: Or make multiple conditions:   `AND price > 355  AND price < 561`

Comment: The `syntax to use near '"Select * from products` suggests the error occurs before this statement, such as the OP is trying to do multiple queries at once...

Comment: I see that you marked this as the answer. You need to know that you got the syntax error from the extra " on the last line. This solved your problem because he removed the " when he made it "between"

Answer (score 3):

in place of this

```
Select * from `products`
where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR
       `product_company`= 'dunkin donuts')
AND (`flavour`='vanilla')
AND (355 < `price` < 561 )";
```

" is causing problem

try this

```
Select * from `products`
where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR
       `product_company`= 'dunkin donuts')
AND (`flavour`='vanilla')
AND (`price`BETWEEN 355 and 561 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN`

```
Select * from `products`
where (`product_company`='mad over donuts' OR
       `product_company`= 'dunkin donuts')
AND (`flavour`='vanilla')
AND (`price` between 355 and 561 )" ;
```